# Question about a dream

Tags: dream, question

Is there any spiritual significance to having a dream about Matan Torah? I had one last night, but it wasn't really an accurate reflection of the event as described in the Torah. I don't remember all of the details, but basically instead of being at Har Sinai it was in a room (maybe in a shul?) with just a handful of people, and there was this kid that Hashem was using as kind of a mouthpiece to speak to them. He (the kid but it was Hashem speaking through him) also reprimanded them for something and that's why it was only a few people instead of the whole nation meriting to be there. Also afterwards the kid got annoyed and started to leave, but someone (presumably Hashem?) said in Hebrew, it doesn't matter because he'll return eventually ("shuvu" something, I can't remember the rest). Should I read anything into this, or is it just coming from my subconscious from having learned the Parshas HaShavua?

Comment: It means you have already, and will continue, to have growth in Torah :)

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking it might be connected with teshuva in some way?

Answer (score 3):

The Talmud gives an opinion that a dream is just a crazy, disorganized, mixed-up assemblage of one's thoughts during the day:

> Rabbi Shmuel bar Naḥmani said in the name of Rabbi Yonatan: A man is shown in a dream only what is suggested by his own thoughts during the day. [Berakhot 55b]

As for interpretations, on the same page you find:

> Rabbi Bana'ah said: There were 24 interpreters of dreams in Jerusalem. I had a dream once and went around to all of them, and they all gave different interpretations. [Berakhot 55b]

Others take dreams more serioualy:

> A dream is one-sixtieth of prophecy. [Berakhot 57b]

Presumably, 59/60th of a dream is meshugas.